# How to disabled input field of a form in a array (dynamic forms) in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

i have a button name 'Add new'.by clicking that button i am pushing data to an array creating the same form.it's creating dynamic form.every form has two field debit and credit. what i want to do is when i will give some value on debit filed then the credit field will disabled also if  i give some value in credit field the debit field will be disabled not for the entaire array only for that specific index. how should i do it?

template file:

```
<template>
<div>
        <form action="/action_page.php">

            <div v-for="(field,index) in fields">
                <div>
                    <button @click="dataRemove(index)" type="button">X</button>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="debit">Debit:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="debit" name="debit" placeholder="Enter debit"
                               type="number" v-model="field.debit">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="credit">Credit:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="credit" name="credit" placeholder="Enter credit"
                               type="number" v-model="field.credit">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="type">type:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="type" name="type" placeholder="Enter type" type="text"
                               v-model="field.type">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <button @click="newfield" class="badge-primary" type="button"> Add new</button>
            <button :disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            field: {
                debit: 0,
                credit: 0,
                type: '',
            },
            fields: [],

        }
    },
    methods: {
        newfield() {
            this.fields.push({
                debit: 0,
                credit: 0,
                type: '',
            });
        },
        dataRemove(index) {
            Vue.delete(this.fields, index);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        disabled() {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary stuff from your code. Make it as minimal as possible in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a reactive `:disabled` property on your fields like

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="f.credit" :disabled="f.debit > 0">
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-6yuri